# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I am getting a list of errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at StudentGrade.main(StudentGrade.java:21)
```

With an example program I copied from my Java Programming book to figure out why I can't get my other programs to work that I have to do by using this program as a base.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentGrade
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws 
FileNotFoundException                                                                       
{
double test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;
double average;

String firstName;
String lastName;

Scanner inFile = 
new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));

PrintWriter outFile = new 
PrintWriter("testavg.out");

firstName = inFile.next();
lastName = inFile.next();

outFile.println("Student Name:  " 
+ firstName + " " + lastName);

test1 = inFile.nextDouble();
test2 = inFile.nextDouble();
test3 = inFile.nextDouble();
test4 = inFile.nextDouble();
test5 = inFile.nextDouble();

outFile.printf("Test scores: %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f " 
+ "%5.2f %5.2f  %n", test1, test2,
test3, test4, test5);

average = (test1 + test2 + test3 +test4
+ test5) / 5.0;

outFile.printf("Average test score: %5.2 %n", 
average);

inFile.close();
outFile.close();
}   
}
```

I have the test.txt file in the same folder as the java file.  But it doesn't have any data in it.

Comment: does your "test.txt" have data in the same order?. "java.util.NoSuchElementException" says otherwise.

Comment: Try counting manually how many lines have your test.txt file, and make sure you are reading the correct data type (String, String, double, double, ...)

Comment: Try to use inFile.nextLine().

Comment: I don't have any data in the test.txt file.  I think I need and end-of-file exception but I don't know how to code that.

Comment: Can you post the file also ?

Comment: "I don't have any data in the test.txt file." ?? .. that's why its throwing NoSuchElementException. How can it read values that don't exist?

Comment: Do you know what the file might look like ? For example it could be a CSV of the form - Name, Score1, Score2, MainExamscore.

Comment: Nope, no idea.  The homework I have to do wants me to be able to store data in a text file and then read it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking whether there is an element in the next position.

ie: before the data is read you must ensure that there is an element in the next position
using this `inFile.hasNext()`.

If only there exist a next element, you must go for the `inFile.next()` or `inFile.nextDouble()`.

If the compiler reads the file and execute `inFile.next()`, its actually expecting an element at that place. And when it does not return anything, it generates a `NoSuchElementException`.

> In short, reading some value that does not exist produce
>   `NoSuchElementException`